# Convert rem to integer value

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to pull out a rem value to an integer.

this.props.viewTitleContainerStyle.paddingTop

Above line of code gives me a value of 1.00rem in the debugger. The viewTitleContainerStyle is stored as theme.sizes.Measures.Measure100. I need to convert this to an integer value for a comparison in another expression. Any way to get this?

I tried parseInt but did not work.

Comment: Which value are you trying to parse? "1.00rem" or "theme.sizes.Measures.Measure100"?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) or [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) precisely for this. It will parse numbers until it sees an invalid number (i.e. rem), at which point it will stop parsing and return you the valid int or float, whichever you asked for. The difference in the two is whether you want it to stop parsing when it sees a `.` or if you want the digits after the decimal to be included.

```js
var value = "1.25rem";
var intParsed = parseInt(value);
var floatParsed = parseFloat(value);

console.log("parseInt():", intParsed);
console.log("parseFloat():", floatParsed);
```

Comment: How do we subtract the pixel value that i got from an offset value?

Comment: @Aditya Can you be more specific? Would `var newPxValue = parseFloat(offsetValue) - parseFloat(pixelValue) + "px"` work?

Comment: @Aditya Or are you wanting to subtract a value in `rem` from a value in `px` and you don't know how to do the conversion? If that is the case, multiply your `rem` value by 16 to get `px`. Similarly, you can divide your `px` value by 16 to get `rem`

Comment: Hello,
Thank you guys for your suggestions. I was able to use your suggestions and research a bit more to get the solution.